# How to Create JSON data with some complexity?

Tags: android, json

I want to create json data of format like this:

```
{
   "Credential":{
      "ref1":"Test",
      "ref2":"test",
      "ref3":"test"
   },
   "ref4":"data"
}
```

I tried a lot, but i did not find a way to do this. Can anyone please help me.
**EDIT:**

I am able to put the data like below:

```
   {
      "ref1":"Test",
      "ref2":"test",
      "ref3":"test"
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html and http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/jsonobject-java-example.shtml . These are very easy and good examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use `JSONStringer` class to do so,

```
JSONStringer jsonstr  = new JSONStringer()
                           .object().key("Credential")
                                    .object().key("ref1").value("Test")
                                             .key("ref2").value("test")
                                             .key("ref3").value("test")
                                    .endObject()
                                    .key("ref4").value("data")
                           .endObject();
Log.i("JSONStringer", jsonstr.toString());
```

Comment: I get an incompatible types error in Idea12 on this. It's expecting a stringer object yet finding a writer.... odd.

Comment: can you please show me the code you are writing with the example JSON string which you are trying to build using pastebin.org @JimWharton Thanks.

Comment: Even if I copy/paste the above example it gives me an error. I can use the super class as the type and it works fine. JSONWriter jsonstr = new JSONStringer(); More of an odd curiosity than an actual problem: http://i.imgur.com/tpTQitU.png

Answer (score 0):

why do not you use [google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)?

```
// get Json string
Gson gson = new Gson();
String strJson = gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

Is not it a better solution?

Comment: what is your problem? your string is valid. do you want to get its related object?